# how to get the file path from the branches in svn

Tags: java, svn, jdbc

I have an SQL file in my repository or branches in SVN which I want to read and execute it.  Because if later that SQL file changes that should not affect the code.

Please help me to figure this out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't quite work out what you're asking here.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: "thanks in advance."  Please use both lower & upper case letters in future.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would like get the content of a fixed revision for your file:

```
svn cat -r <rev> <file>
```

You can use

```
svn log -l 1 <file>
```

to get the last revision number of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that data from the svn info command.

```
svn info <file> | grep "Last Changed Rev"
svn info <file> | grep "URL"
```

In the URL you can find what branch it is in.